# Vector gets overwritten by each ->push_back()

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I'm attempting to have a class called "Client" that has a vector of pointers to pointers to "Files". When I push an element to the list, it appears to work fine, but when I add more than one, the entire vector gets overwritten with the most recent element.
so say "one" gets added to the vector, the vector is then "one".
but say you then add "two" to the vector, the vector is then "two two"...
I'm probably doing something obvious wrong, but I have been stuck here for so long I do not know what to do.

Here is where I add to my vector

```
void share( std::vector<Client*> *cliIP, int connfd, char* buf ){
    File *file = new File(buf);
    int place;
    for (int i = 0; i < cliIP->size(); i++)
        if( cliIP->at(i)->getConnfd() == connfd ){
           cliIP->at(i)->addFile(file);
           place = i;
        }

    cliIP->at(place)->printFiles();
}
```

here is my constructor:

```
Client::Client(const char *IP, int portNum, int connfd){
    _IPaddr = IP;
    _portNum = portNum;
    _active = 0;
    _connfd = connfd;
    _cache = 0;
    _listOfClients = new std::vector<Client*>;
    _listOfFiles = new std::vector<File*>;

}
```

here is addFile:

```
void Client::addFile( File *file ){
    _listOfFiles->push_back(file);
}
```

Comment: you didn't post enough.  It is not clear what you are doing and what is happening and what you tried to fix it.  You need to work on your example to make it simple and short and most likely you will fix it yourself in the process. http://sscce.org/

Comment: One problem is that `place` can potentially be uninitialized.

Comment: Kind of bizarre coding convention. It's like using `ArrayList[] vector = new ArrayList[]{new ArrayList()};` in Java.

Comment: Don't use so much `new`. This isn't Java.

Comment: If your `connfd` value could be the same for all of your `Client` objects, then your for loop could result in this behaviour. Are you sure they're unique?

Comment: So the code loops over the indices that your `vector` says are valid, but the code also checks index validity with `at()`? Belt and suspenders. Just use `(*cliIP)[i]`. Even better, pass `cliIP` as a **reference** rather than a pointer, which will get rid of all those `->`s.